# How can I extract part of a string based on a pattern using Windows CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have an input let's say:

`DummyString-v1.0.0`

and I would like to extract everything after `v` to get: `1.0.0`

How can I achieve this in CMD?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "string=DummyString-v1.0.0"
SET "string=%string:*v=%"
ECHO %string%
GOTO :EOF
```

where the `:*substring=replacementstring` syntax is applied meaning "every character form the start of the variable (`string`) up to the substring (`v`) is replaced by the replacement string (*nothing*).

Comment: You are a STAR!, very elegant solution. Just one thing though, if input has another `v` then this will break so I had to also add the `-` to address the problem. so I modified it to be: `SET "string=%string:*-v=%"`

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

call :split "DummyString-v1.0.0" "v"
echo %last_part%

exit /b 0

:split

set "string=%~1"
set "splitter=%~2"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


rem ** Two empty lines are required
echo off
for %%L in ("!LF!") DO (
    for /f "delims=" %%R in ("!splitter!") do ( 
        set "var=!string:%%R=%%L!"      
    )
)
for /f "delims=" %%P in (""!var!"") DO set "last_part=%%~P"
endlocal &(
  set last_part=%last_part%
  exit /b 0
)
```